# word entry in an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to make a program that will read up to 20 words entered by the user and stored in an array of strings.  The program will ask for additional words until 20 words have been entered or until the word 'done' has been entered.  The idea is that these words will then be entered into a matrix to create a word search program.  I'm stuck on scanning in the words entered by the user.  I'm a new programmer so any words of advice is very beneficial.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char string[20][100];

  printf("Enter up to 20 words to hide in the puzzle.\n");

  printf("Enter the word 'done' after your last word if entering less than 20    words.\n");
  scanf("%s\n",c)

  printf("Entered words:\n");




  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better allocate your words (and the array to hold them) using `malloc()`. That allows you to store more and longer words than you thought about.

Comment: Word entered does not allow duplicates?

Comment: You are going to need `scanf()` -- or `fgets()` and `sscanf()` -- and some loops to get your data into the program.  You will need to ensure that you limit the loop so that only 20 entries are allowed.  You will need another loop to print out the words in the array of strings.  There are few words of 100 characters, so you're safe enough there.  While there is dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` et al), I suspect that is complicating things more than you're ready for at this stage in your programming career.

Comment: I made a mistake when posting the code..I've got scanf in I'm confused on how to incorporate the loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straight-forward but bug-fixed variant of the code provided by [developer3466402](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3466402/developer3466402) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22868649/15168).

I've used a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop since that neatly summarizes the action in the `while` loop.  I added `n` to record how many words were entered, leaving `i` as a loop control variable (yes, once upon a long time ago I wrote Fortran too).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char words[20][100];
    int i = 0;
    int n;

    printf("Enter up to 20 words to hide in the puzzle.\n");
    printf("Enter the word 'done' after your last word if entering less than 20 words.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter word %2d:\n", i+1);
        if (scanf("%99s", words[i]) != 1 || strcmp(words[i], "done") == 0)
            break;
    }
    n = i;
    printf("%d words entered\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Word %2d = [%s]\n", i+1, words[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

It worked OK for me entering 0, 1, many and 20 words.  We can debate the newline after the prompt; it has pros and cons, but that's generally true.  I chose to echo the data after the loop rather than within the loop.  Be aware that with some programs, echoing in a loop can appear to work where echoing after the loop shows a problem.

Example run (with an early exit):

```
$  ./rw
Enter up to 20 words to hide in the puzzle.
Enter the word 'done' after your last word if entering less than 20 words.
Enter word  1:
aleph
Enter word  2:
null
Enter word  3:
absolute
Enter word  4:
twaddle and nonsense
Enter word  5:
Enter word  6:
Enter word  7:
elephants are done for
Enter word  8:
Enter word  9:
8 words entered
Word  1 = [aleph]
Word  2 = [null]
Word  3 = [absolute]
Word  4 = [twaddle]
Word  5 = [and]
Word  6 = [nonsense]
Word  7 = [elephants]
Word  8 = [are]
$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char words[20][100];
    char temp[100]="\0";
    int i=0;
    int end=0;  //0 false and 1 true
    printf("Enter 20 words or enter done to exit.\n");

    while(i <=19 && end==0) 
    {
        strset(temp,'\0');// resets array temp to NULL's everytime

        scanf(" %99[^\n]",temp); //this is scan set, to read a string without '\n'
        printf("Given:%s\n\n",temp);

        if(strcmpi(temp,"done")==0)//compares given input with "done".if "done" is entered. zero is returned
            end=1;//when 0 is returned this end=1 will break the loop.
        else//if input is not given "done" then copy temp array to words[i].
        {
            strcpy(words[i],temp);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using **words[20][100]** directly, I have used a temporary array named **temp** to initially store the input,because at the end i don't want to store "done" into **words[20][100]**.Assuming that "done" is used only to end the input process and it is not the actual word to store.But you can change this program to your need.

Comment: That's pretty good code, but still doesn't check the return value from `scanf()` which is necessary.  Pascal requires boolean flags like `end`; in C, you can use `break;` unless you're being taught by a Pascal programmer.  For my money, a `for` loop is cleaner than the `while` loop, but it is partly a style issue. Using `< 20` (or more generally `< N` is more idiomatic C than `<= N-1`. Using `strcmpi()` for case-insensitive comparison is not 'standard C' though it is available on Windows.  It marginally limits the portabiliy of your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Yes you are right i could have used  `break;` previously i did always use `break;` and `continue;` almost for every loop but i learned that its not good structured programming. They should be only used to increase the efficiency of algorithms(ex:- when searching a number in array the loop has to be broken at that point where number is found). Secondly i used `i<=19` to make things easy to understand.Yes using i<N or i<N-1 is more idiomatic and good.I didn't not know that `strcmpi();` is **non standard.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish something like below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char words[20][100];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter up to 20 words to hide in the puzzle.\n");

    printf("Enter the word 'done' after your last word if entering less than 20 words.\n");
    while (i < 20) {
        printf("Entered words:\n");
        if (scanf("%99s", words[i]) != 1 || strcmp(words[i], "done") == 0)
            break;
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to upvote an answer that suggests `gets()`, regardless of any other merits. Not even when the code is clearly toy code.  **Never** use `gets()`. It is poisonously lethal as a function (a program that uses it cannot protect itself from abuse) and is no longer a part of Standard C (though it is still available in essentially all standard C libraries).  Use `fgets()`, but remember it includes the newline.

Comment: I agree with @Joanthan but I really don't knwo how use fgets in this context, then I changed by scanf.

Comment: `words[i] != "done"` , `scanf("%100s", words[i]);` : bad. and `printf("%s\n", &words[i]);` remove `&`.

Comment: Thank you for not using `gets()`. You are now testing `words[0]` before anything is assigned to it (which is part of what BluePixy is saying).  Of course, you can't compare strings like that either (use `strcmp()`.  You should also detect errors and EOF from `scanf()` -- always check your input functions.  You probably need to remove the string comparison from the `while` loop and have `if (scanf("%99s", words[i]) != 1 || strcmp(words[i], "done") == 0) break;`.  Note the 99; the size you specify in `scanf()` does not include the terminal null (ancient history and backwards compatibility).

Comment: Also, the `printf("%s\n", words[i]);` should not have the `&`. Although it will 'work', the types are all wrong: you're passing an `char (*)[100]` to a function that expects a `char *`, give or take some const-ness.

Comment: Incidentally, you'd use `if (fgets(words[i], sizeof(words[i]), stdin) == 0) break;` and then `words[i][strlen(words[i])-1] = '\0';` and `if (strcmp(words[i], "done") == 0) break;` or something fairly close to that.  You could add `assert(strlen(words[i]) > 0);` before zapping the newline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler..I replaced the while loop with the if statement a few comments above and it seems to be running fine but only one word is entered and then the program ends..how should i modify this statement so up to 20 words can be entered?

Comment: Thanks for all comments, I edited the code now with the last sugestions of @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically allocate memory to store words. If the user inputs more than 20 words, then you can use `realloc` function to allocate more memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int wlimit = 20;
    int wcount = 0;
    int retval;  // to save the return value of scanf
    char wstring[100+1];  // +1 for the terminating null byte
    char **wlist = malloc(wlimit * sizeof *wlist);

    if(wlist == NULL) {
        // handle it
        printf("not enough memory to allocate\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *temp;

    while(1) {
        if(wcount >= wlimit) {
            wlimit *= 2;
            temp = wlist;
            wlist = realloc(wlist, wlimit);
            if(temp == NULL) {
                printf("not enough memory to allocate\n");
                wlist = temp; 
            }
        }
        retval = scanf("%100s", wstring);

        // if the input string is done, then break out of the
        // loop else keep taking input from the user
        if(retval != 1 || strcmp(wstring, "done") == 0)
            break;

        // strdup function creates a new string which is a duplicate
        // of the input string and returns a pointer to it which can
        // be freed using free
        wlist[wcount++] = strdup(wstring);
    }

    // do stuff with wlist
    // after done, free the memory
    for(int i = 0; i < wcount; i++)
        free(wlist[i]);

    free(wlist);
    wlist = NULL;

    // stuff

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is recommending `malloc()` and `realloc()` helpful to someone struggling with loops?  You should check the return value from `scanf()` to protect against EOF.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True but I don't know how can we let the user enter more words until the input is `"done"`.

Comment: My reading of the specification implied by the question is: enter up to 20 words, but if you want to enter fewer than 20, you can enter 'done' to indicate the end.  Checking for EOF is just routine self-protection; EOF can happen any time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It says that the program will ask for additional words until 20 words have been entered. Is it safe to check the return value of `scanf` for `1` and `break` the loop in case of failure?

Comment: That would be my recommendation (`if (scanf(...) != 1) break;`).  So your update is OK.  I reread the specification; it is ambiguous because of repetition.  However, given that looping is causing some grief, I feel fairly sure that requiring 20 and allowing up to 40 is not the intended reading of the specification (not least because it doesn't cover the use of 'done' to end the list of entries 21..40).